# Webcam Problem (Robaxo RC100)

Tags: drivers, usb, camera

First of all, I am completely new to Linux in general so I do apologize for not knowing basically anything. I am using Pop Os which I was told is based on Ubuntu and I have a problem with my webcam. Basically, when I plug in my camera Skype does recognize and also shows me video but when I try to use it in a call it goes completely black and does not show any video. I also did test it whit Cheese and it does not recognize it. The webcam model is Robaxo RC100 and as far as I can see it says USB PHY 2.0: USB Camera.

I did run the command `lsusb` and got this:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 067: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:4938 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Audio USB
Bus 001 Device 101: ID 13b1:0039 Linksys AE1200 802.11bgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43235]
Bus 001 Device 103: ID 1224:2a25 Jieli Technology USB PHY 2.0
Bus 001 Device 102: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Oh and if you need any additional info I will be happy to provide it

Is there anyone that can help me with this, I normally do not care about the camera but I need it for work.
Thanks for all the help :)

Update: After reinstalling Cheese my camera does work in the Cheese app but still black in Skype

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Skype?  What about using a different USB port?  Seeing if there is a setting on Skype to choose which camera to use?